# Twitter Oauth via PHP WITHOUT cURL

Tags: php, twitter, curl

My server does not support cURL.

I want to update my status via php.

How to do that without cURL?

Again: WITHOUT CURL!

Answer (score 6):

Here’s how you can tweet without using cURL with PHP.
We have two options-

**With stream context**

Php function stream_context_create has the magic. It creates and returns a stream context with any options passed.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$username = 'username';
$password= 'WHATEVER';
$message='YOUR NEW STATUS';
function tweet($message, $username, $password)
{
  $context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'header'  => sprintf("Authorization: Basic %s\r\n", base64_encode($username.':'.$password)).
                   "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
      'content' => http_build_query(array('status' => $message)),
      'timeout' => 5,
    ),
  ));
  $ret = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml', false, $context); 
  return false !== $ret;
}
echo tweet($message, $username, $password);
?>
```

**With socket programing**

PHP has a very capable socket programming API. These socket functions include almost everything you need for socket-based client-server communication over TCP/IP. fsockopen opens Internet or Unix domain socket connection.

```
<?php



$username = 'username';

$password= 'WHATEVER';

$message='YOUR NEW STATUS';



$out="POST http://twitter.com/statuses/update.json HTTP/1.1\r\n"

  ."Host: twitter.com\r\n"

  ."Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode ("$username:$password")."\r\n"

  ."Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"

  ."Content-length: ".strlen ("status=$message")."\r\n"

  ."Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"

  ."status=$msg";



$fp = fsockopen ('twitter.com', 80);

fwrite ($fp, $out);

fclose ($fp); 

?>
```

Taken from here: http://www.motyar.info/2010/02/update-twitter-status-with-php-nocurl.html

Hope htis helps.

If you need any more help let me know as i am a php programmer myself.
thanks

**PK**

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php
/*
* using file_get_contents
*/

$key = '';
$secret = '';
$api_endpoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=news'; // endpoint must support "Application-only authentication"

// request token
$basic_credentials = base64_encode($key.':'.$secret);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  =>    'Authorization: Basic '.$basic_credentials."\r\n".
        "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8\r\n",
        'content' => 'grant_type=client_credentials'
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

// send request
$pre_token = file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', false, $context);

$token = json_decode($pre_token, true);

if (isset($token["token_type"]) && $token["token_type"] == "bearer"){
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'GET',
            'header'  => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$token["access_token"]       
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $data = file_get_contents($api_endpoint, false, $context);

    print $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: How would you wire your code sample to post a tweet?  I changed the endpoint to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Testing and it causes me to get a 400 Bad Request.  From what the docs say, this probably means I am not authenticated to post a tweet.  I believe you need more auth credentials than just the key and secret?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the [oauth pecl extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth). See [here](http://hasin.wordpress.com/2010/04/04/complete-oauth-script-for-twitter-and-linkedin-using-pecl-oauth-extension/) for details.
EDIT: you need to install the pecl extension